# Entity Framework 6 is not mapping my columns correctly using Attributes

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6 to query data from a database. The database existed before the code and belongs to another application, so I cannot modify the database at all. I believe I am using a code first approach, even though the database already exists(Forgive me as I'm new to EF). The issue is that I am not able to pull back data for a column that is setup as follows;

```
[Column("ITEM_QTY")]
public decimal ItemQuantity { get; set; }
```

Now if I rename the property to ITEM_QTY, it pulls the data correctly. I'm not sure what I'm missing. I can pull data from any other field correctly, but this field returns 0 regardless of whats in the DB. Can anyone provide any direction?

In another discussion, someone had suggested a possible issue with the underscores in the column name. Not sure if that could be it, but adding for  info. Thanks.

Edit: Adding code used to query database. Note that this was setup before I started working on the project, so following same convention;

```
var t = this.Database.SqlQuery<InventoryDb>("select top 100 * from COMPANY_INVENTORY with (NOLOCK) where COMPANY = @CompanyName",
                new SqlParameter("CompanyName", companyName)).ToList();
```

Comment: Just to rule out some possible issues, could you try changing the column attribute to `[Column("ITEMQTY")]` and see if that works? Maybe there is some implicit mapping configuration that strip the underscore out.

Comment: @frostshoxx there isn't afaik, I am using column names with underscores in many of my projects (in `Column` attribute). This annotation should work no problem. Can you post the line which brings you no data?

Comment: @frostshoxx Just tried that, no luck.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius added to post.

Comment: @BrianMorrison I just realize you're using inline SQL query to fetch the data. Worst case scenario, you might want to consider changing `top 100 *` to `top 100 [column1], [column2],[column3]` instead. This way you can even rename the column `ITEM_QTY` to `ItemQuantity` and call it a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Column` attribute will be ignored if you are using custom `SqlQuery<T>` on the `DbContext`. You need to pass the Sql statement with the alias for the property name that matches your entity.

```
var t = this.Database.SqlQuery<InventoryDb>("select top 100 Item_QTY as [ItemQuantity], ... other columns ... from COMPANY_INVENTORY with (NOLOCK) where COMPANY = @CompanyName",
            new SqlParameter("CompanyName", companyName)).ToList();
```

**EDIT:**
Was checking this further out of curiosity and it appears that EF should respect the `Column` attribute if you used the `DbSet.SqlQuery` instead. I have not tried this though. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx)

```
var t = this.Inventory.SqlQuery("select top 100 * from COMPANY_INVENTORY with (NOLOCK) where COMPANY = @CompanyName",
            new SqlParameter("CompanyName", companyName)).ToList();
```

Comment: Confirmed with your first suggestion. Will have to explore the second one as that looks cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: _Was checking this further out of curiosity and it appears that EF should respect the Column attribute..._ - it doesn't.

Comment: I've done further testing. Using either form:

`code` db.Database.SqlQuery<model>(sql)
or
`code' db.modelSet(sql)

with either the column attribute or with the fluent API results in a mismatch between the datareader and the model where the property names do not exactly match those in the Sql.

EF definitely absorbs the column mapping as I have a trace in there (for the fluent API)

Comment: Sorry for the sloppy editing above. I got blocked after 5 minutes when I hit enter by mistake